How to inject component dynamically based on data type?
I have different sections od the applications (I am using standalone components so don't want to say modules). I dont want to have direct dependencies between sections.
Now, one of the sections is search.
When user does a search, different search result types can be shown.
Let's say searchResultType1, searchResultType2, searchResultType3 (they are search result item components). All of them can be shown at once in the list, mixed. They are shown using ngFor in a template.
Each searchResultTypeX is implemented in its corresponding section of the app.
I am thinking defining abstract class that all searchResultX types implement but they are all injected into search component as abstract class.
I know how to implement this when I have one, but can't figure out if there is a way to inject all of them based on data type returned by search.

There's no way for angular to inject those components automatically. However, you can load those component dynamically. For that you can create some component factory, and use NgComponentOutlet to render components - https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader
Here's stackblitz with example how to do it
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dnfg41?file=src%2Fsolution-with-factory.component.ts
I made factory method, but it would be probably best to have it in separate class.
If you need to pass some inputs for the component, you can also do it through NgComponentOutlet. You could modify the factory to return object {componentType, inputs}, and later pass both to NgComponentOutlet

So you have three types and the output can be a combination of these types properties.
Ensure for each type you have the ?: is added to the properties. So that you can merge all three types, but it's not necessary that all the properties of the merged types need to be defined!
export interface searchResultType1 {
    test1?: string;
    test2?: string;
    test3?: string;
}
...

Do this for all the types, now create a common type searchResultTypeX contains the & operator, so that all the properties exists within the singular type.
export type searchResultTypeX = searchResultType1 & searchResultType2 & searchResultType3;

Now you can set searchResultTypeX as the return type for the merged properties
When you are working with HTML. You can use a function to asset the Type as searchResultType1 or searchResultType2 or searchResultType3 so that the typing is preserved wherever needed!
isSearchResultType3(value: searchResultTypeX): searchResultType3 {
    return value as searchResultType3;
}

html
@if(isSearchResultType3(item); as itemTyped) {
   <!-- some html code which uses the typed item -->
}


Thanks for your answer! This part solves for common interface between the data types. Now, the problem remains with components for presenting each type: how to reference&load all corresponding component types without establishing hard dependency between sections of the app?

@tlzg Could you try @switch to switch between components. all components are standalone, so they are independent of each other is my understanding!

You are right, they are independent but you still have to import them. What I would like to avoid is to have cross sections direct imports. That't why I am thinking about some abstract class (or some way to represent common interface) and somehow resolve it to particular type without direct imports. I hope it makes sense.

@tlzg a component is a block of code that can be reused effectively. they are encapsulated as a whole and need to be imported, if you want to do it a different way, then just create a common class (need not be abstract) where you add all the functionality, but just think how large the component might be and the effort needed to maintain it, individual components are much easier to maintain, then a single component which has a lot of code (even if its done through inheritance)!
